# Beginner issue with the while loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

So I am trying to learn C++ and one of the questions on my textbook is this:

> (Sales Commission Calculator) A large company pays its salespeople on
>   a commission basis. The salespeople each receive $200 per week plus 9%
>   of their gross sales for that week. For example, a salesperson who
>   sells $5000 worth of chemicals in a week receives $200 plus 9% of
>   $5000, or a total of $650. Develop a C++ program that uses a while
>   statement to input each salesperson’s gross sales for last week and
>   calculates and displays that salesperson’s earnings. Process one
>   salesperson’s figures at a time.
>
> Part B) You must check if user typed minus sales of less value of 0.
>   If it is less than or equal to zero, you should show "You are losing
>   money for company, you are fired" and keep it going.

So I wrote my code which works for the scenario above but my problem is I'm not sure how to use the while command in this situation so once the everything goes through the if/else statements, it does it again starting with "Enter your sales".

Here is the code: (Would like to basically add a while to this somehow so it can keep repeating itself under this scenario and start from beginning once salary is computed, but don't know how to that.)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double sales = 0.0, salary = 0.0;

    cout<<"Enter your sales amount(> $0.00): " ;
    cin>>sales;

    if (sales <= 0)
    {   
        cout<<"You are losing money for company, you are fired"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    else 
    {
        salary = (sales * 0.09) + 200;
        cout<<"Salary this week is $"<<salary;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I had a bug in my original answer. It's fixed now. Please accept answer if it helped you :-)

Comment: It would help if you explained exactly what you're unsure about when using a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ask you how many times to run the loop (number of employees) and run the loop that many times:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number_of_employees = 0;
    double sales = 0.0, salary = 0.0;

    cout << "Enter number of employees: " << flush;

    cin >> number_of_employees;


    if (number_of_employees == 0) {
        cout << "There are no employees" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (number_of_employees < 0) {
        cout << "There can't be negative employees!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while(i < number_of_employees) {

        cout<<"Enter your sales amount(> $0.00): " ;
        cin>>sales;


        if (sales <= 0)
        {   
            cout<<"You are losing money for company, you are fired"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }

        else 
        {
            salary = (sales * 0.09) + 200;
            cout<<"Salary this week is $"<<salary<<endl;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I run it in VS 2015, It repeats loop of sales > 0 but if I input a negative value it doesn't loop and terminates.

Comment: Yes that's right! You could have a `cin` before the for loop where the user would input the amount of employees. The loop will run as many times as the number of employees. If the user enters a negative number, output `"There can't be negative employees!"`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually used your code you made before changes and made the loop a max integer so its "infinity". The changed one is good too because it asks for employees which is also useful. Once again thanks for the help and fast responses.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the number of sales people to know the amount of the loops.This shoud work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double sales = 0.0, salary = 0.0;

    cout<<"Enter your sales amount(> $0.00): " ;
    cin>>sales;
    cout<<endl;
    int numberOfSalesPeople;
    cout<<"Enter the number of salespeople";
    cin>>numberOfSalesPeople;
    cout<<endl;

    int j=0;
    while(j<numberOfSalesPeople) {

        if (sales <= 0)
        {   
            cout<<"You are losing money for company, you are fired"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }

        else 
        {
            salary = (sales * 0.09) + 200;
            cout<<"Salary this week is $"<<salary;
        }
        j++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and quick response.